# C# Regex Character Class / String Pattern - to identify exclamation mark

Tags: c#, regex, if-statement, expression, character-class

I want to do something like this --- if an expression contains exclamation mark, error; else, no error.

The expression may be a value itself or math/string function. Example as below: 
expr = abc; 
expr = 123; 
expr = concatenate(123,abc); 
expr = sin(0.5);

I'm using Regex library to identify the string pattern.
For every of the expression above, they didn't prompt out error (expected result), except for the last expression "expr=sin(0.5)", it prompts out error! Which it supposingly not to do so.

So just wonder if I've written the string pattern wrongly? Or which part of the code that I need to modify in order to get the correct result?

Provided with my code:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(_exprWithVariableValues, @"[.*!+.*]+"))
    _result = "Invalid value";
else
    _result = "Correct";
```

Comment: What's wrong with _result = _exprWithVariableValues.Contains('!') ? "Invalid value" : "Correct"; ?

Comment: @JerryFederspiel well, that was embarrassingly easy. I have went into the wrong direction to use only Regex, sigh. Thanks so much! Answer below is another solution btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much too simple for regular expressions. Your regular expression literally needs to be this:

```
!
```

..or just check it with C#:

```
if (_exprWithVariableValues.IndexOf("!") > -1) {
    // invalid
}
else {
    // valid
}
```

Comment: well, your answer is right as well. Thanks very much! I'm quite fresh in programming field and I guess I need to improve a lot at current stage. Again, thanks.

Comment: No problem. When you look at Regular Expressions, your first thought should be: `is this too much for my current need?`. Regex is powerful sure, but in most basic use cases it is much too heavy a tool for the task. Its like using a chainsaw to break a toothpick in half... just easier if you grab the toothpick and break it with your hands :)

Comment: Yea, what you are so so true. At first instinct when I saw other people using Regex for regular expression, I tend to follow that direction to solve my problem as well, that I've neglected the fact that this is actually a basic use case compare to others. Thanks for the little story, it kinda 'wakes' me up :) I'll bear it in mind and continue to improve myself. Thank you :)

Comment: No problem at all. Have fun! :)